# javascript on change needs refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I'm trying to make a textbox, with a counter to show how many signs you have left (pure for user interface purposes, not the actual validation).

I tried to use this code:

```
function checkRemainingChars () {

    var maxChars = 500;
    var text = document.getElementById('textArea').value;
    console.log(text);
    var usedChars = text.length;
    var remainingChars = maxChars - usedChars;
    var message = "<p>" + remainingChars + "out of " + maxChars + " characters remaining </p>";
    console.log(message);
    $('#remaining').append(message);
}


$(document).ready( function () {

    $('#textArea').on('change',checkRemainingChars());

});
```

where #textArea is the textarea where the user puts his text, and #remaining is an aside with the message how much signs he has remaining.

this only works when the page loads/refreshes. then I tried to add something simple, to eliminate possible mistakes in my code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    $('#textArea').on("change",alert(1));

});
```

but even here I only get the alert when I refresh the page. What do I have to do to make the text update as soon as the user types something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the method and assigning what it returns to the event listener, not assigning a reference to the method.

```
$('#textArea').on('change',checkRemainingChars()); 
                                              ^^
```

drop the `()`

```
$('#textArea').on('change', checkRemainingChars);
```

If you need the method to run when the page loads, you can trigger the change event.

```
$('#textArea').on('change', checkRemainingChars).trigger("change");
```

or you can call `change` directly.

And finally you are appending messages to the element for what is remaining. I do not think you want append, you probably want to use

```
$('#remaining').html(message);
```

Comment: This basicly fixes the problem, but I have to remove focus before it updates. I can use on keyup, but the moment someone copy-pastes anything, they have to remove focus or continue typing before it updates, any suggestions for that?

Comment: use `"change input"`

Answer (score 1):

The `change` event is only triggered when you leave the `textarea`, after you have changed its content.  It is probably more useful to use the [`keyup` event](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/).

```
$('#textArea').keyup(function(){
    var chars_remaining = 500 - $(this).text().length;
    alert("remaingin chars: "+chars_remaining);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look attached snippet :

```js
function checkRemainingChars () {
    var maxChars = 500;
    var text = $('#textArea').val();
    var usedChars = text.length;
    var remainingChars = maxChars - usedChars;
    var message = "<p>" + remainingChars + "out of " + maxChars + " characters remaining </p>";
    
  $('#remaining').html('');
    $('#remaining').html(message);
}

  $('#textArea').on('change keyup paste',checkRemainingChars);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="remaining"></div>

<textarea id="textArea" rows="4" cols="50">
I'm trying to make a textbox, with a counter to show how many signs you have left (pure for user interface purposes, not the actual validation). 
</textarea>
```

Comment: I'm aware of the keyup event, but what about copy-pasting code? autocomplete?